# Are cells closed in CW Complexes and proving finite CW complexes are compact

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

So I am trying to understand the topology on cw complexes. I know that the $n+1$ skeleton of X is formed as

$$X^{n+1} = \{ X^n \sqcup D_{i}^{n+1} \}/ \sim$$

where $\sim$ denotes $s \sim f_i^{n+1}(s)$ where $s \in \partial D_{i}^{n+1}$ and $f_{i}^{n+1}: \partial D_i^{n+1} \to X^n$ are the attaching maps.

Now I know X is the union of all the n-sletelons.

Now I want to know is each cell closed? I was thinking with the weak topology a set $A$ is closed in X if $A \cap X^n$ is closed in each $X^n$. So an n-cell must be closed in each skeleton since $X$ is formed by taking a closed n-cell and attaching it along the boundary.

So each $n$-skeleton $X^n$ is closed? Can I extend this idea to say that $X^n$ is compact because $X^0$ is finite and each n-cell is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (by H.B), so that makes $X^0 \sqcup D_i^1$ compact so then $X^1$is compact since the quotient map is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, each $n$-skeleton $X^n$ is closed in $X$. But $X^0$ is not required to be finite and the attaching construction $X^n \mapsto X^{n+1}$ may involve infinitely many $D_i^{n+1}$. Therefore you cannot conclude that the $X^n$ are compact.

A simple example is $X = \mathbb R$ with $X^0 = \mathbb Z$ (which has the discrete topology). Then $X^1 = \mathbb R$ is obtained by attaching the cells $D^1_i = D^1$, $i \in \mathbb Z$, via the maps $f^1_i : S^0_i \to X^0, f_i^1(-1) = i - 1, f_i^1(1) = i$.

Comment: so then if you can add infinitely many cells, how can you argue that $X^n$ is compact. In your example $X^1$ is the whole real line, which is not compact...

Comment: @Sasha This is what I said: You cannot conclude that the skeleta are compact. The real line is an example for that.

Comment: but I thought finite-dimensional cell complexes are compact... it says that in Hatcher's algebraic topology.

Comment: @Sasha It is not true. Where does Hatcher say this?

Comment: on page 520 - "A finite CW complex, that is, one with only finitely many cells, is compact sinceattaching a single cell preserves compactness"

Comment: I suppose then my question about compactness should not have reflected n-skeletons but rather finite CW complexes. I got the two mixed up.

Comment: However, using my argument with regards to finite CW complexes would that work in arguing compactness?

Comment: @Sasha Correct, a CW complex is finite iff it is compact. And your argument for finite $\Rightarrow$ compact is correct.